# using OraclePerformance Counters via c# code

Tags: c#, oracle, performancecounter

I'm trying to use the OraclePerformance Counters via C#-code.
I don't want to use the PerfMon!
Without someones help, I would not even found the correct page for the Oracle Counter, which is: [enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15296_01/doc.111/e15167/featConnecting.htm#CJADIIFD)

Now im struggeling on how to use them. It doesn't work like the SQL-ones because it always crashes telling me, that the Instance-Name could not be found...

I would really appreciate a working example for the Oracle Performance counters because the whole Internet doesn't seem to have one.

Comment: Check your connection string.  The driver has to be the same driver and version that is shown in your link.  the webpage says it is using Oracle Data Provider of Net.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: the connection string is correct and works.

Comment: Where is connection string working?  Have you used it since any updates?  When was last time it worked?  I'm suspecting one of three things 1)  You updated the driver and now you have to update the connection string to work with driver installed. 2) You are using an ODBC connection and have to update your ODBC connections 3)  The failure is actually occurring when you try to connect and the connection is failing.  Recently you have to upgrade the TLS version in Client from 1.0/1.1 to 1.2/1.3.